# Triangle Dilation by Radius Distance

Tags: geometry, vectors, triangles

I'm attempting to follow the accepted solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17561/how-to-shrink-a-triangle):

However, I cannot seem to get $k$ to equal out to the correct scalar value.

In my use case I made up a triangle of the following 3 points ${(0,0),(921,0), (460.5,265)}$ and I want to reduce the radius by 25.

Here is what I have so far:

$a=\sqrt((921-460.5)^2+(0-265)^2)=531.305$

$b=\sqrt((0-460.5)^2+(0-265)^2)=531.305$

$c=\sqrt((0-921)^2+(0)^2)=921$

$P = a+b+c = 1983.61$

$A = (.5)(921)(265)=122032.5$

$r = 2*A/P=123.041$

$Q = c/2,r = (460.5,123.041)$

$k=r/(r-x) = 123.041/(123.041-(-25))= 0.831$

Solving for points A and C

$A’ = A+(Q-A) * k$

$Xa=0+(460.5-0)*.831 = 382.676$  Is this a vector from the inscribed center back towards 0?
$Ya=0+(123.041-0)*.831 = 102.247$

$Xc=460.5+(460.5-460.5)x.831 = 460.5$

$Yc=265+(123.041-265)x.831= 147.197$

Would the inverse of k be $k'= (r+x)/r$ so if I wanted r to grow by 200 k would be

$k = (123.041+200)/123.041 = 2.621$?

I would comment in that question, but I do not have the reputation to do so, sorry for asking a question related to a solved problem but I'm really just not understanding the solution.

Could someone please show me how to arrive at the correct solution.

Comment: You should show your own work so that someone can point out where you might be making an error. As far as the linked question goes, I might’ve used the circumcircle instead if the incircle to determine the dilation, but either way, the resulting radii and center for the triangle in your question are not “nice” values, so the required scale factor isn’t going to “nice,” either.

Comment: @amd I added some details as to how im generating my values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer and the problem exists in the original question.

$k = R/(R-X)$

This is not accurate. Using the numbers above for points on the x-axis where y is 0 and solving for k using $A'=A+(Q-A)*k$ would give the following:

$25=0+(123.041-0)*k$

$k = 25/123.041 = .203$ which is just $X/r$

Comment: I agree. I would have expected the formula to be $k=X/R.$